# Converted from HTTP to HTTPS... errors & log in forms not working - PHP?

Tags: php, ssl, https

We have converted our site from HTTP to HTTPS, and when our login forms are being submitted, we are getting the message:

"Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?"

Our cookies are not being set in PHP and the page is basically just refreshing.

What do we need to do to amend our forms so that they work with HTTPS?

Comment: Can you show us the code of an example form tag?

Comment: Post the generated HTML code for the form, and the code that's generating it. My guess would be that you have hardcoded `http://` in the URLs for the forms instead of choosing the right protocol depending on the connection.

Comment: (@Kyle, as for a deleted other question of yours, please don't replace your question with *Nevermind, I managed to fix it :)* We're a Q&A site, not some help forum. Thanks!)

Comment: @Arjan, the question was resolved before it was answered, therefore it isn't really a question anymore. If it had of received answers I would have left it up.

Comment: No, @Kyle, then you could have used the "delete" link instead. Please see the license that applies to all posts. Vandalising them by replacing the content is not appreciated. Apart from that: why not post the answer yourself then, for all of us to learn if someone has the same issue in the future? These sites are not help forums.

Comment: @Kyle, @Arjan is correct.  Please don't delete or deface questions.  If you fixed it, you can always answer with a paragraph detailing how you did it.  Helps people who have the same issue.  If you're always finding yourself fixing things yourself, consider waiting a bit before asking a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check page source. If it contains something like:

```
<form action="http://yoursite.com . . .
```

Then it sends the user to the nonencrypted site.

Comment: I managed to fix it straight after posting this question, it was due to having a base href as "http". Thanks :)